# Pass Jquery variables to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an app where if you click on a div, the data-id will be put into a variable, which will give PHP the select parameters to look for. Here's my code to better explain it.

HTML:

```
<div class="box" data-id="caption"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.box').click(function () {
        var caption = $(this).data('id');
});
```

After Googling I found the best way to do this is through AJAX, which I then proceeded to try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: ({ caption }),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. If there's a better way to do what I mentioned above, I'm open to new ideas.

**EDIT**

Here is my PHP code.

```
if(isset($_GET['caption'])){
    echo $caption;
    $select = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE text = '".$caption."'";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your `data` parameter in your ajax call is invalid. It should be something like `data: {caption: caption}`.

Answer (score 2):

Look through the [api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) at jQuery.

> Your data key should contain a **json** object -

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {caption: caption},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: It was just the error from the error: function(), nothing else.

Comment: @Vic You will need to modify your question to include the PHP code as well as that's what's causing the error.